# find the repartition function: $ F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \, dt$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f$ be the function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} k^2 xe^{-kx} & \text{if } x\geq0, \\0 & \text{if } x <0.
\end{cases}$$

I have to prove that $f$ is a repartition density  for every $k >0$, and for this I prove that : $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t) \, dt=1 .$$

Now I must find the repartiton function : $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \, dt$ but I have no idea. How should I proceed ?

For example if $x\in (-\infty,0)$ $F(x)=0$? and if $x \in (0, \infty)$ then $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(t)\,dt +\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$?

thanks :)

Comment: yes i think it is correct,you can also use case of improper integrals ,or introduce   limits,but instead of $x$,use  infinity

Comment: Not sure I understand: you are able to show this is a PDF but not to compute its CDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is the mean for exponential distribution, where $\lambda = k$, if you take one $k$ out of brackets. That mean equals $\lambda^{-1}$, therefore the full integral is $k \cdot k^{-1} = 1$

The exponential distribution density:

[image]

Comment: Who upvoted this? The distribution in the question is NOT exponential.

Comment: Seriously? Why?

Comment: Just read and compare with your answer.

Comment: Everything is OK.

Comment: Wow. Read again.

Comment: Oh you mean that $x$. Ok

Comment: "This integral is" still not "the mean for exponential distribution" (neither a mean nor for the exponential distribution).

Comment: $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = k \cdot \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} kxe^{-kx}dx = k \cdot M(expdist(k)) = k \cdot k^{-1} = 1$

Comment: After a thorough revision, the post is correct.